# In Pyspark, how do you filter a spark DataFrame using an array column that intersects with one or more items in a list [item1,item2,...]?

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark

---

## Problem:

---

I am trying to use `pyspark` to apply a common ***conditional filter*** on a Spark DataFrame.  Ultimately, I want to return only the rows whose array column contains one or more items of a single, stand-alone list provided.

In SQL, it's easy.  I would use the following code template:

```
select <columns>
from <table>
where arrays_overlap(<array_column>,array(<list>))
```

However, when I translate this to spark, my code fails.  Triggering an "error

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, array, arrays_overlap

df.select(*).where(arrays_overlap(col(<array_column>), array(<list>)))
```

> AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `<1st item in list>` cannot be resolved.

This is strange, because if I apply `array_contains` condition in `pyspark`, the code will run as expected.  However, `array_contains` does not help me here because it only looks at one item, not a list.

What is the correct pyspark equivalent to the SQL `where` condition shared above?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  To use a list (rather than a column) as a filter, I need to replace `array(<list>)` with `array(*map(lit,<list>))`.

So the proper solution will be:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, array, arrays_overlap, lit

df.select(*).where(arrays_overlap(col(<array_column>), array(*map(lit,<list>))))
```